# storing and showing images

Tags: php, image, file-upload, file-storage

I still really don't understand image storing and showing.

Let me give you an example, what I did first (people say my logic is a bad idea).

I did at first, every user has a folder with an `user_id`, and after the form was submitted it saves the image with an `unique name` in to this folder and the image name too, with the extension in the database, and I've shown the image matching the file name in the folder with the saved name in the database,

Example (here let's skip the unique name just to make it more clear a bit)

an user uploads an image named `butterfly.jpg`

the image is stored in the database

```
id | name          |
1  | butterfly.jpg |
```

and stored in a folder too with the same name

```
/images/user_id/butterfly.jpg
```

and showing the image this way

```
<img src="images/unser_id/<?php echo $name ?>" alt="">
```

So it matches the names (I hope I was clear sorry if not)

So I know my logic is a bad logic, because storing the names in the database will lead to a huge one, maybe to other problems in the later future

And what I would like to ask if its not a big request, if someone could write down a logical thread with some example codes (I'm not asking to write it for me), just to give me the idea what I'm missing

And other questions about what I read about

Some developers say, they only store the image folder name in the database, that is okay, but how I am able to show those images if only the folder name is stored? because it will maybe have more than one image like 3 one the original image and 2 other thumbnails.

So please don't hate me with this question, I only asked this because I would like to learn and get advice from a more experienced developer.

Comment: well if you don't want to store image names in db maybe you can store just folder name and than iterate trough dir and display images in loop?

Comment: About which huge problem are you talking this will lead to? I mean if you want to learn something, you should ask your question, not hide it ;)

Comment: If each and every row in the images table takes up `512` bytes (it wont) and you have 1 000 000 images, that would lead to a database size of 488(+/- a few MB of overhead) megabytes. Which is not huge at all (your images will take up significantly more) Don't worry yourself about such things. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @vanneto just a quick question, so its not a problem then if i store the image name in the db and on the server and match the names to show? and thank you for your answer, it helped me :)

Comment: No, not from a size perspective at least. What happens if the user uploads an image with the same name though? I'd use the `id` of the image store it on disk. Then if the user can download it, use the PHP `header()` function to set a name equal to the one the user uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right path. The correct way of doing it is - to upload the file to your server and then put the image path into your database, as far as i can tell, you're doing it right. :-)

Comment: why i thought it is bad bacause, im not storing the imahe path in the db i store the name, and storit it on the server as well and than match the result, so this is okay too? sorry for the stupid qustions

Comment: As long as you're consistent throughout your app, I don't see a problem with it. I can see the benefit of creating a folder for each user and storing the images there, that way multiple users can upload images with the same name etc. As long as you don't store the images directly into your database you should be absolutely fine.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, and sorry, i cant give you an upvote i need 15 perutation :(